# Not sure why this Java Null Pointer Exception is happening

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a method that return an array of files in a given directory that is giving me a null pointer exception when executed. I can't figure out why.

```
private ArrayList<File> getFiles(String path) {

    File f = new File(path);
    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(f.listFiles()));

    return files;
}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: please post full stack trace, nullpointer at which line?

Comment: sorry, exception on this line: `ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(f.listFiles()));` thanks

Comment: Possibly because `f` is a path that refers to a non-directory on the file system, so `f.listFiles()` returns `null`

Comment: @dnault - its not a dupe, this post has a specific question, not generic. @Nayuki - should `path.listFiles()` not list all the files in that directory?

Comment: Read [the Javadoc for File.listFiles](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles\(\)) and you'll see that it "Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs."

Comment: I see. So what would be the easiest way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Check that the path name is correct first or at least check `f` for null before trying to call a method on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This NullPointerException is thrown when the path specified while initializing the file is incorrect (doesn't exist).
In such cases it is always advisable to add some null checks(protective code) in your method.
eg:
if( f != null) { //get the list of files }

Comment: Thanks, I understand why the error is occurring. I have added a null check: `private List<File> getFiles(String path) {

        File f = new File(path);

        if(f != null) {
            ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(f.listFiles()));
        }else{
            ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        return files;
    }` but the error is still happening, therefore f is not null.

Comment: Are you sure the path you provided is a directory ? See this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles(). May be adding a f.isDirectory() may help : if(f != null && f.isDirectory())) { //get list }

Answer (score 0):

may be casue by `f.listFiles()` return one null array.you can watch the variables in debug model